# matrix with external elements and dashed separation lines

Tags: matrices

I am trying to make a matrix with external elements and dashed separation lines for clarification. I have gotten pretty far using the `blkarray` package. However, I have failed to add a horizontal separation line between rows f and g, only inside the matrix. Also, I would like the separation lines to be dashed.

**EDIT**:
Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I would like both separation lines to be dashed. Will try no if this works with any of the provided answers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 H =
 \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
  & a & b & c & d\\
  \begin{block}{c(cc|cc)}
   e & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
   f & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\ 
   g & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
   h & 3 & 4 & 5 & 7\\
  \end{block}
 \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 H =
 \begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[first-row,first-col]
  & a & b & c & d\\
   e & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
   f & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
   \hdottedline
   g & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
   h & 3 & 4 & 5 & 7\\
 \end{pNiceArray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Ouput of the above code]

If you want dashed lines, you can draw them with Tikz, you can define a custom type of line with `custom-line` which provides a way to use whatever Tikz style of line you want. You need at least `nicematrix` version 6.10a (2022-06-26).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,            % <- for the vertical rules
       command = hdashedline , % <- for the horizontal rules
       tikz = dashed ,
       total-width = \pgflinewidth   % <- optional
     }
  }

\begin{equation}
 H =
 \begin{pNiceArray}{ccIcc}[first-row,first-col]
  & a & b & c & d\\
   e & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
   f & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
 \hdashedline
   g & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
   h & 3 & 4 & 5 & 7\\
 \end{pNiceArray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Ok, here I can easily make the vertical line dotted by replacing `cc|cc` with `cc:cc`. Any suggestions of how I could turn those dotted lines into dashed lines?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\BAhhline` with `~` column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 H =
 \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
  & a & b & c & d\\
  \begin{block}{c(cc|cc)}
   e & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
   f & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  \BAhhline{~..|..}
   g & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
   h & 3 & 4 & 5 & 7\\
  \end{block}
 \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]